# compile classpath

Tags: java, netbeans, compilation, classpath

I am very new to Java and using an IDE. I have a problem I was wondering if some body could help me please. I compiled HelloWorld project and saved it but when I right click the main project the Compile Classpath is empty. I know I need to add a JAR file to the libriaies but I am unsure as what file to add, this is giving me problems as I can't compile the project outside of an IDE. I am using NetBeans on a Windows7 system.

Is there anyway you could help me please?

This is my code which runs fine

```
public class helloworld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Hello OCA World");
    }
}
```

And this is the location for my jdk bin C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin
and this is it inputted into the System Variables\ PATH

> C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_{xx}\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Wireless WLAN Card;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\PrC:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\

Comment: I'm guessing it's that "{xx}" part instead of the "09" that's the actual path.

Comment: The PATH is not related to the CLASSPATH

Comment: It looks like you need to add classpath to your system environment. Follow this link http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/ece122/help/setenvironment.htm

Comment: madth thanks I understand that I was just adding that in to make sure the PATH was in correctly as I have been told I didn't do it right the first time. It is just the Classpath really I need help with. But if the PATH is wrong nothing will work

Answer (score 0):

to compile

`javac -classpath .;<path of your jar>;  xxx.java`

to execute

`java -classpath .;<path of your jar>; xxx`

Comment: Thanks What I really want to know is does my compile classpath jar file come from my netbeans folder or the Java folder? I have loads of files ending in .jar

Comment: jar files first comes from <JRE PATH>/lib and <JRE_PATH>/lib/ext , if it can not be found ,then it searched in your classpath, whatever it is in IDE or not.